# [JAVA]How to call the method "itemStateChanged"

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, itemlistener

So, I have this method;

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event){
        if(event.getSource() == temasJogo){
            if(event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
                indiceTema = indiceTemas[ temasJogo.getSelectedIndex() ];
            }

        }
    }
```

just for this `JComboBox`

```
temasJogo = new JComboBox(temas);
        temasJogo.addActionListener(this);
```

I need it to modify an attribute of my class so that it selects the other theme of the game. The problem is, I can't manage to call this method anywhere. I know the answer will be something really simple, but I truly need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, `itemStateChanged` is a method of `ItemListener`, assuming that you've implemented the `interface` in some way.

In order to have it called, you need to register the instance of the `ItemListener` with the `JComboBox`

```
temasJogo.addItemListener(this);
```

as an example

See [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) and [How to Write an Item Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/itemlistener.html) for more details

Comment: I knew it was something really stupid, I used an ActionListener even though it's an ItemListener. Thank you so much!

Comment: It's always the small things ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just implements the interface in a class.

Ex.

```
class sample implements ItemListener
```

Apply the listener on JComboBox

```
        temasJogo = new JComboBox(temas);
        temasJogo.addItemListener(this);
```

After that, below function will be called when item changes.

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event){
        if(event.getSource() == temasJogo){
            if(event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
                indiceTema = indiceTemas[ temasJogo.getSelectedIndex() ];
            }

        }
    }
```